# How to find which release a changeset is in

Tags: linux, git

What's a way to find a release that a given changeset is in?

For example given this changeset:
http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=commit;h=50d3e6399a61fca53c5c440a79f71299db66b803

How do I use git to tell me the earliest release this changeset made it into?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `git describe --contains $SHA1`, which will give you the oldest tag that your commit is reachable from.